# Small brushless motors: What are the inherent trade-offs between 56V and 18V motors?

Tags: voltage, dc-motor, torque

While researching tools in the quest to become a handyman, I was captivated by the fact that one of the top brands sells 54V (60V max) cordless power tools while another sticks to 18V. Two questions about electrical motor theory come to mind:

1. Is there any theoretical or practical difference between brushless motors at 18V and 54V to make one voltage design inherently better for one reason or another (torque, temperature, efficiency, etc).
2. If there are no/negligible differences between 18V and 54V motors, is there a DC voltage level at which the difference become significant in a non-theoretical way?

Comment: Lower current may be kinder on the connections, and may allow smaller switching devices depending on where the voltage/current sweet spot is with how devices on the market now happen to have been optimised (I remember a few years ago there was a lot of development into devices suitable for '3 car batteries' or 42 V, for alternator/starter applications). But a battery of a given weight, and a given weight motor, will likely have the same nominal power and run time, regardless of voltage over the 'reasonable' range of 10 to 100 V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a whole lot not being said here.

Resistive losses (aka heating) is equal to \$P=I^2R\$ while powered is \$P=IV\$. That means that if design the load appropriately, you double the voltage and halve the current you can deliver the same power but halve the resistive heating.

However, to make a motor run the same at higher voltage, you need more turns which means longer wire. If the motor is otherwise the same, that means you need thinner wire to fit more turns into the same sized stator and/or rotor. Longer, thinner wire means the resistance goes up offsetting this.

So an equivalent higher voltage motor is more or less the same efficiency as an equivalent lower voltage motor. What the lower current does is make things easier to get power to the motor. For example, wires going to the motor, and brushes in the motor (if there are any) can be smaller because they carry less current. If there are electronics controlling the current it also makes things easier for them since the circuit board traces can be thinner. It can also make things easier for transistors but higher voltage transistors also have higher resistance sort of like the motor so there's a balance to be struck here. The transistors need to be made or chosen so the resistance doesn't go up faster than the voltage that the transistors can tolerate and are being used at.

Answer (score 1):

> the Milwaukee tools simply add more sets to increase mAh capacity
> while the top-end DeWalt tools run them in series to create a 56V
> battery at 1/3 the mAh (which I realize is the same Watt-hours either
> way). To my main question -- which is better?

As you say, it's the same Watt-hours either way. The difference is the higher voltage motor draws less current for the same power. This make no difference to the motor - it's the same amount of copper and iron so the same losses and motor heating.

But it does make a difference for the wires and connectors, which have to handle higher current at lower voltage. That means they have to be thicker and heavier to keep losses down. On the hand they don't have to handle as much voltage, so the insulation can be thinner and spark gaps smaller. Above a certain voltage it becomes a shock hazard, requiring more insulation and better shielded connectors.

Another issue is the batteries. Higher voltage requires more cells, making the battery more complex and more expensive. Controllers may also be more complex, and have higher losses above a certain voltage because less efficient components are required (eg. IGBTs vs FETs).

The optimum voltage is that which needs the fewest cells without making the wiring and connectors too large. Therefore a small tool will generally be designed to work off lower voltage. As power increases the optimum voltage increases, until it requires special high voltage components and/or becomes a safety issue. The limit for battery powered tools may depend on electrical regulations, for example in [Australia and New Zealand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra-low_voltage#Australia_and_New_Zealand) AS/ACIF S009 Clause 3.1.78.1 Extra-Low Voltage (ELV) states:

> "a voltage not exceeding 42.4 V peak or **60 V DC** [AS/NZS
> 60950.1:2003]"

Answer (score 0):

Higher voltage also means more arcing - there is no perfect answer. The failure of one cell on a series chain means no current. One dead cell on a parallel setup means that leg of the parallel power source is gone and reduced torque (depending on how Milwaukee handles dead cells in control logic). My experience with DeWalt and Milwaukee tools is a single datapoint but by far, my preference is Milwaukee brushless series 18 V. The brushed motor versions of the same tool are about the same performance as the DeWalt tool.

Comment: Does higher voltage mean more arcing? Because often arcing is a result of currents through inductances, and the currents are less with higher vootages.

Comment: Switches have voltage and current limits for a reason.  It is a system question more than a simple yes/no question whether series is better than parallel. Which company accounts for more failure mechanisms. I don't know.  I hear more sob stories about one brand and I see more old, dirty versions of the other brand as contractors come through our facility.

Comment: Arcing distances are a function of voltage, not current.

Comment: True but as far as arcing is concerned, it's not operating voltage that is the concern (well, your switch has to be enough to isolate that at minimum I guess), but the peak voltage that arises during interruption which is a function of the operating current and inductance, not the operating voltage.

Comment: A somewhat simplified model of arcing would be: Flashover distance increases with voltage. Once you have an arc, the current will determine the "width" of it. As for breaking using a mechanical switch, it's the reverse, high current determines the start of it and the voltage determines how long it will be sustained until extinguish.